# Visual Studio 2008 C# compiler const if statement problem!

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, constants

When the following code in put in Visual Studio 2008 C#, The word "`System`" is underlined and is marked as "unreachable code":

```
public static class Program
{
    const int motors = 1;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (motors < 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine("program run.");
    }
}
```

This is obviously incorrect, and I'm wondering if anyone can explain the behaviour.  Thanks!

[edit]
I'm using VS 2008 Professional.

Comment: It appears that this does not happen in VS 2010. Perhaps this is a bug in the static analysis engine in 2008?

Comment: Do you have resharper installed? Their warning system is known to throw up incorrect warnings.

Comment: @CMP : Nope, no resharper.  @Whomever: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a clean and build. I suspect there is a glitch somewhere as it is the `return;` line that is unreachable.

I just tried this in 2008 and it is the return line that I am warned about.

Comment: good point. The editor could have just screwed up where the error was rendered.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with project state or anything like that.  I have this problem in a large example, and to make sure it was really a problem, I created a brand new solution, pasted the code above in there, and got the exact same problem, so I copied it here.  It's been happening for perhaps 3 weeks now, and I've restarted many times, rebuilt, etc.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are no problems with your code. Could be that a previous error already corrected produced the underline, in that case Visual Studio did not update the UI correctly. That has happened to me very often, my advise is (re)build the project and check if the underline has gone.

Comment: The answer is almost unreadable.  I filed for an edit and will change the vote when I can after it's edited..

Comment: @Limited i corrected the grammar. I'm a spanish speaker that learn english basically seeing movies, reading books, and listening music, so i tend to make errors in verb uses. I seriously think that i need to read a book about grammar to improve my writings, :/